# Software that can reproduce sound from mike on speakers LIVE

Tags: audio, recording, microphone, voice

I am looking for a software to record the voice through a mike and also reproduce this sound "live" on the speakers.

Please suggest me if you are aware of any such softwares.

Thanks
Chandra

Comment: I don't understand your question - it sounds like all you need is a splitter from the mike; one end to the speakers and one to a recording program. I don't see why the software should have to forward the sound to the speakers as well.

Comment: Migrate to SuperUser?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with DirectShow on Windows.  C++ or .NET could wire it up fine.  GraphEditPlus could do it without any coding.

http://www.thedeemon.com/GraphEditPlus/

But as Adam V said, a hardware splitter is easier/cheaper.

[image]

http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021802&p_id=669&seq=1&format=2

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try this one and also the software..

Comment: Shouldn't that go the other way? One input, two outputs?

Comment: @Adam V, you're right. I fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Pro Tools from Digidesign.  It comes with both the hardware and the software.  They have several different versions/packages. The cheapest is Pro Tools LE using an MBox for the hardware interface. I think $499 or so. It all comes together, the hardware and software.

http://digidesign.com/index.cfm?langid=100&navid=28

Comment: $0.85 Y splitter or $500 Pro tool set?  I like these options.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 can do it out of the box, [see here for details](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2009/08/04/a-few-of-my-favorite-win7-sound-features-capture-monitor-aka-listen-to.aspx). Previous versions of Windows can do it if the hardware supported it, but not all hardware does, obviously.